# Rails Devise adding user when log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I use Devise gem to log in, registration and others purposes and it's running great. 
Problem starts, when I log into the application and I want to add another user from inside.
I only see "You are already signed in." and nothing else.

So I create another controller for this action- "manager", but nothing changes.

Controller looks like this:

```
class ManagerController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.create
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And routes:

```
devise_for :users

resources :manager
```

How can I have both - registration from outside and adding users from inside?

Rails 4, Devise 3.2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise::RegistrationsController has `require_no_authentication before filter` by default.

So it's needed to skip it:

You need to overwrite registration controller. Paste this lines at starting of the controller

```
skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Because we want to use registration controller after user loges in.

Basically registration comes first in picture but here we need to use it inside, so no need to make more controller and just overwrite devise methods and controller.

-------------------------------------------------------------Updates------------------------------------------------------------

In model just add this method

Model/User.rb
    before_validation :generate_pwd

```
def generate_pwd
  your_generated_pwd = @Random password string
  self.password = your_generated_pwd
end
```

In Route.rb

```
resources :managers
```

In views/managers/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and use new_manager_path to open this form. Form will use registration_controller's create method.

Comment: I've added to my ManagerController this two lines, but nothing changed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing reverse of the question. You have registered one user using devise then you have another model named manager which creates manager, by default it will generate manager after login of admin/user. This question is how to use registration controller of devise after login. devise never do this, so for that you need to override this method as i said.

Comment: If you want to go this way then just put "before_filter :authenticate_user!" at the top of the manager controller. you can create manager this way. hope you can understand what i mean to say

Comment: For to be more precise, ManagerController is just a controller, without model. 
I have right now model User with a role:string, and nothing else. After adding "before_filter :authenticate_user!" to ManagerController nothing changed.

Comment: Yea I have the solution... Please check my updated ans.

Comment: Still nothing. I create a little application, only with Devise and this problem:
https://github.com/brateq/Adding-user-after-login-with-Device

Comment: you can clone code from here https://github.com/savanr/devise-add-user-after-login

Comment: And this is exactly what I need :)
For full satisfaction, I changed two things:
from
      def new
    if user_signed_in?
      super
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_url, :alert => "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
    end
  end

to 

    super

and 

    # sign_up(resource_name, resource)

to

            unless user_signed_in? 
          sign_up(resource_name, resource) 
        end

After this, everything works like I a charm. Thank you very much!